# Getting max value from object in an abstract class array

Tags: java, polymorphism

I´ve been trying to solve this.
I wanted to get max ClassA value.
So I have an interface and 2 classes

```
public interface Something {

}
```

---

```
public class ClassA implements Something{
    private int a;
    public ClassA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
 }
```

---

```
 public class ClassB implements Something{
    private int b;
    public ClassB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Something[] array = new Something[10];
        array[0] = new ClassA(1);
        array[1] = new ClassA(2);
        array[2] = new ClassB(0); 
        ClassA max = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i]!=null && array[i] instanceof ClassA){
                //what do to here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that I put this there,

```
if(array[i].getClassA()>max.getClassA()){
                max = array[i];
}
```

but its not working, so what should I do to make it working ?
Thanks for answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  What did happen? What do you see when you step through the code in your debugger?

Comment: `getClassA` does not exist in your class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing the code doesn't even compile.  This is because it is not enough to determine an object is a type, you have to cast the reference to access it's methods or fields.

```
ClassA a = (ClassA) array[i];
if (a.getA() > max.getA())
    max = a;
```

BTW This is not an example of Polymorphism as you are not using an overridden method here.

An example using polymorphism might look like

```
interface Something {
    boolean isA();
    int getA();
}

class ClassA implements Something {
    // fields and constructor
    public boolean isA() { return true; }
    public int getA() { return a; }
}

Something[] array = { new ClassA(1), new ClassA(2), new ClassB(0) }; 
ClassA max = null;
for (Something s : array) {
    if (s.isA()) {
       if (max == null || max.getA() < s.getA())
           max = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok now I know how, and if I do the polymorpfism, should´nt the boolean isA() and int getA() be in ClassB aswell ?

Comment: @krkus yes, `isA() { return false; }` and getA can `throw new UnsupportedOperationException();`

Answer (score 0):

Do a null check on max and then compare the values

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
    if(array[i]!=null && array[i] instanceof ClassA){
        if (max == null || array[i].getA() > max.getA()){
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
}
```